# why i can't get alert info in js?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>    
var currentNumber = 0;    
while (currentNumber <= 12) {    
  alert(currentNumber);    
  currentNumber = currentNumber + 2;    
}    
<\script>
```

I want to  prints out all even numbers from 0 to 12 , Why i can get nothing when run it?

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that your ending `<script>` tag is causing the problem. The slash is pointing the wrong way. It should be `</script>`, not `<\script>`.

Try this code

```
<script>    
var currentNumber = 0;    
while (currentNumber <= 12) {    
  alert(currentNumber);    
  currentNumber = currentNumber + 2;    
}    
</script>
```

Comment: That does solve the problem, but shouldn't type="text/javascript" be there as well? **Edit**: As an attribute to the `<script>` tag

Comment: type="text/javascript is not required as per latest standards, I believe as of HTML5.

Comment: @asimes Not in HTML5, see [here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) for more details

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a syntax error because the `<script>` tag is not closed properly. It isn't `<\script>`, it's `</script>`. This same pattern applies to all tags, make sure you have the correct slash. 
Maybe you can use a text editor that can highlight mistakes like this.

I am using SublimeText and you may have a try.

Comment: Why did you post the same answer after scrblnrd3 already posted?